# How to use HTTP POST on Xcode

Tags: ios, http, http-post

Sorry, beginner question here.I am trying to use HTTP post to retrieve an XML document from a URL, and there are some parameters which I need to include in the POST request.I have got the code from [this website](http://blog.stathat.com/2011/11/28/http-post-in-many-languages.html) in the Objective C section and am starting to understand it. But what I now need to try and do is use that class in my app. Here are the parameters I need to include:

```
URL: https://admin.poslavu.com/cp/reqserv/ 
dataname=tangere_techno&key=dBkeY&token=dBt0kEn&table=menu_groups
```

￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://admin.poslavu.com/cp/reqserv/"]];
[request setValue:@"gzip" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept-Encoding"];
[request setHTTPBody:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"dataname=tangere_techno&key=dBkeY&token=dBt0kEn&table=menu_groups"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSError *error = nil; NSURLResponse *response = nil;
NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
if (error) {
    NSLog(@"Error:%@", error.localizedDescription);
}
else {
    //success
}
```

Data should be your XML info, you'll need to parse it first though. You should try looking at Apple's docs for more information. If you are trying to make the request asynchronously try this:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://admin.poslavu.com/cp/reqserv/"]];
[request setValue:@"gzip" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept-Encoding"];
[request setHTTPBody:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"dataname=tangere_techno&key=dBkeY&token=dBt0kEn&table=menu_groups"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];


AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:req];
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject){
    NSData *data = (NSData *)responseObject;
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
[operation start];
```

Comment: Thanks, before I accept it, I'd just like to ask how I can log the response?

Comment: This code has three issues: 1) you are not correctly checking for an error condition. You might wonder why you sometimes log an error while there is actually none. 2) you use a synchronous method call for an inherent asynchronous operation. This will unnecessary spawn a thread and block it for the duration of the network request. This is at least suboptimal - but may become a big concern when RAM is scarce (and this is always true on mobile devices). 3) you don't check the HTTP status code and the MIME type of the response. This is the minimum of checks you should do.

Comment: @MichaelScaria I was just about to give up, thanks soo much!!!!!

Comment: @CouchDeveloper do you have any alternative code then??

Comment: Yes I have ;)  But before I answer, you may also search with these key words: "NSURLConnection",  "asynchronous", "POST". I'm sure you will find answers. Also, consult the Apple docs for NSURLConnection, there are also examples for simple POST requests, read how to check for errors for methods whose last parameter is a pointer to a NSError*.

Comment: Thanks, but I am prompting for an answer incase anyone else with similar problems came accross on this page.

Comment: A solution varies greatly in number of lines of code depending on what level you want to accomplish in your app: toy, sample, hobbyist, amateur, advanced, sophisticated, professional.  ;)   I would suggest to start with "advanced" which involves NSURLConnection in asynchronous mode implementing the delegates. This is the basis for the more higher levels, which deal with custom authentication, memory efficient loading techniques, parse and download in parallel, progress notification, robust error handling, ...  So what do you require?

Comment: @CouchDeveloper I added the request with AFNetworking, which I usually use.

Comment: @MichaelScaria This code is fine  ;)

Comment: Sorry, but I can't figure out what to import to use AFHTTPRequestOperation?